Positions of pictureboxes not same in runtime and in design
I'm using C# WinForms, and I noticed that positions in design and runtime are completely different. Let me demonstrate:
I have a picturebox named player at location (687, 705). Using this line of code:
player.Location = new Point(687, 705);

I changed player location to its location, it should be here (blue box):

like in design, but ends up here:

It expands the window, and appears in the corner. Here:

are my forms properties. It's not working for any AutoScaleMode option.

There's not enough information here for us to diagnose the issue. Please read this and update your question accordingly. You probably need create a test project that doesn't include all the superfluous stuff and give us information from that. The code for your form's designer and user code files should be sufficient for us to reproduce what you're doing so we can, in theory, see the behaviour you're seeing. If it doesn't happen for you in the new project it's obviously project-specific so you need to check for specific differences,

Where is the code setting the location? Please show the whole method. Your code will probably not be executed at design time. In the "but ends up here:" image I don't see the blue box.

It's in the bottom right corner. I wrote that line of code in Form1_Load method.

Form_Load is not executed at design time. So, it is not a surprise that the positions are different from runtime. Have you set an anchor of the picture box other than top-left? E.g., if it is bottom-right, it will follow the bottom-right corner of the window.

I didn't set any additional anchors.
